# I want to find a topological embedding $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X$, yet $X$ is not homeomorphic to $Y$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This is related to a problem of showing that none of the intervals $(0,1], (0,1), [0,1]$ are homeomorphic to another, since it's in the same problem block.  I've tried using $f(x) = 1 - x \ , f(x) = 1/(x-1)$ between varying pairs of those intervals to no avail.  Do I need a function as complicated as the topologist's sine to show this?

Comment: You can embedd each interval in the other one by $f(x)=\frac13+\frac13 x$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now.  I guess I kept looking for a surjection as well.

Comment: With your additional condition (that it is also surjection), it seems to be identical to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325293/is-this-a-sufficient-condition-for-two-spaces-to-be-homeomorphic-proof-or-count)

Comment: This questin is about the other problem you mentioned: Is there exist a homemoorphism between either pair of $(0,1),(0,1],[0,1]$; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240414/is-there-exist-a-homeorphism-between-either-pair-of-0-1-0-1-0-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

Define $f : (0, 1) \to [0, 1)$ to be the inclusion. This is an embedding.

Define $g : [0, 1) \to (0, 1)$ by $\displaystyle t \mapsto \frac12t + \frac12$. This embeds into $[1/2, 1) \subseteq (0, 1)$.

But $(0, 1)$ and $[0, 1)$ are not homeomorphic. If you remove any point from $(0, 1)$ you get two disconnected components. However, if you remove $0$ from $[0, 1)$ you still have only one component.